# Configure defaults for underlying SocketsHttpHandler used by HttpClientHandler in a net6 console app referencing a netstandard2.0 library

Tags: c#

I have a net6 console app that is referencing a netstandard2.0 library project that uses a static `HttpClientHandler` used by all `HttpClient`s in the library project code (i.e. `using client = new HttpClient(httpHandler, disposeHandler: false)`. The library project is also used by a net48 project so can't be retargeted.

I am worried about stale DNS on active connections. With the `SocketsHttpHandler` we can configure the `PooledConnectionLifetime` property, but I don't see anything similar available on `HttpClientHandler` yet I know that in my net6 console app `HttpClientHandler` will actually be implemented with an underlying `SocketsHttpHandler`... is there any clean way to get at that setting in my net6 app (I'm less worried about my net48 app at this time, but bonus for any insights on stale DNS concern there)?

Comment: I'm not sure things work as you described them. `PooledConnectionLifetime` is relevant when you have a pool of handlers and is used by `HttpClientFactory` to decide when an idle handler can be reused for different purposes. But in your case, there is a single static handler. I don't see any pool in your description.

Comment: Also, what does this mean `uses a static HttpClientHandler used by all HttpClients in the library project code`? Does the lib defines the static handler and creates the client when needed? I know nothing about your architecture, but it sounds incorrect. Instead, the library should receive the `HttpClient` and leave its creation to the application.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 6, while using HttpClientHandler, you can't access underlying SocketsHttpHandler properties. In order to do this you can use custom HttpClientFactory.

```
public class MyHttpClientFactory : IHttpClientFactory
{
  private readonly SocketsHttpHandler _socketsHttpHandler;

  public MyHttpClientFactory()
  {
    _socketsHttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler();      
    _socketsHttpHandler.PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
  }

  public HttpClient CreateClient(string name)
  {
    return new HttpClient(_socketsHttpHandler, disposeHandler: false);
  }
}
```

usage:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = (new MyHttpClientFactory()).CreateClient())
{
   // 
}
```

Comment: What is `HttpClientFactory.SetFactory`? Where it comes from?

Comment: @Artur i corrected that part